# What's the meaning of the expression "Grab a hold"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, lyrics

What does it mean to "grab a hold"? There is a song by Cyndi Lauper that says

> If you wanna grab a hold, let it go...

Answer (score 12):

The phrase is actually "grab *ahold*", and when you grab ahold of something, you grasp it or hold onto it.

For example, if you are watching a scary movie with someone, you might grab ahold of their arm during the frightening parts.

Answer (score 3):

- **grab a hold of yourself**: don't lose heart, control yourself

> *Grab a hold of yourself, grab a hold of your mind and change your life.*

[ldoce](http://www.ldoce.com) defines:

- **Catch/grab/seize etc hold of something** = start holding something quickly and firmly

> *She grabbed hold of letter and tore it open.*

- **grab a hold of** [sb's arm]: take hold of someone or something with a sudden or violent movement

> *Kay grabbed hold of my arm to stop herself falling.*

Note: The term get a hold of somebody/something has a different meaning.