# Get hold of, get ahold of, get a hold of

Tags: differences, idioms, prepositions, adverbs

Under what circumstances would you prefer one of the following over the other two?

1. Get hold of
2. Get ahold of
3. Get a hold of

Comment: Related: [“Grab a hold”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13628/whats-the-meaning-of-the-expression-grab-a-hold)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The three variations of this expression exist and are acceptable.

The meaning actually depends on what follows *of*, so *get hold/ahold of someone* means communicate with/reach someone and get *hold/ahold of something* means obtaining/literally reaching out for something.
And I believe they convey the same meaning, with "get ahold of" being spoken English (apparently because it's easier to pronounce) for "get hold of" and "get a hold of" being specifically used for physical actions.

Comment: bit confused by your answer here. You seem to be comparing "get hold/ahold" of  with "get hold/ahold of"

Answer (score 4):

“Get ahold of” doesn’t exist. “Get hold of” and “Get a hold of” are mostly interchangeable, but “get hold of” is more often used with people: “get hold of Mr. Jones and tell him…”, and “get a hold of” is used with things, like gaining expertise: “I think I’ve finally gotten a hold of this subject…”.

**Edit:**
New information: “ahold” does exist, but it’s a slang.
Thanks, @NewAlexandria.

Comment: [It](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+ahold+of) does exist!

Comment: Oh. It doesn't seem to be used often, because if you google "define ahold", you get something about a retailer. "Ahold" seems to be used with literal physical grasp, though.

Comment: Thanks for your take on this. And yes, "get ahold of" does exist. According to google: "get hold of" 132,000,000 results, "get a hold of" 54,800,000 results, "get ahold of" 16,200,000 results

Comment: "get ahold of" seems to be [primarily American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+ahold+of%2Cget+a+hold+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=6&smoothing=3). The [British](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+ahold+of%2Cget+a+hold+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=6&smoothing=3) use "get a hold of". I believe the only difference between these two is the spelling (so this answer would be correct in the U.K.).

Comment: "ahold" is not a proper word, @asymptotically , so you were right the first time.  "ahold of" is a colloquialism, but the OED does nto define "ahold" as a word out of context of the colloquialism

Comment: According to Grammar Girl, ahold has been used in the English language since 1600 http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/a-hold-or-ahold?page=1 Dictionary.com designates it as informal, not as a colliquialism.

Comment: @NewAlexandria It doesn't just exist. It's completely proper, is a standard coinage based on [*a-*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8), & has been in use in this sense since the 19th century at least.

Comment: Downvoted because the original answer was wrong and the edited answer is still wrong. The word "ahold" exists, is very old, is not slang and not a contraction of "hold" and the indefinite article.

Comment: @Christian Source? From MW: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ahold (and every other dictionary I looked up)

"Definition of ahold
informal 

First Known Use of ahold
1850, in the meaning defined above

History and Etymology for ahold
probably from the phrase a hold"

A word can be both old and slang.

Comment: https://etymologeek.com/eng/ahold or https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ahold for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think that grammatically speaking, *get **a** hold **of** yourself* doesn't make much sense - and in fact it seems to me that [people originally recognised this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20a%20hold%20on%20yourself,get%20a%20hold%20of%20yourself&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

That linked NGram chart shows how the more "logical" *get a hold **on** yourself* was actually more common when both expressions started becoming widespread in the 20s. And [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20a%20hold%20on%20yourself,get%20a%20hold%20of%20yourself,get%20hold%20of%20yourself&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that plain *get hold **of** yourself* has always been more common than either version with the word *"a"*.

Whilst I don't disagree with other answers saying that ["get **ahold** of yourself"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22get%20ahold%20of%20yourself%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is "incorrect", that link to over 15000 written instances shows that in the minds of many, it really is a kind of "adverb" that gets round the inherent grammatical problem in what's now an established idiomatic usage. Somewhat akin to, for example ["Get along with you!"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get%20a%20hold%20on%20yourself%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1700,cd_max:1919&lr=lang_en#hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1700,cd_max:1919,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22get%20along%20with%20you%22&oq=%22get%20along%20with%20you%22&gs_l=serp.3...16036.17114.1.17394.5.5.0.0.0.0.157.442.4j1.5.0...0.0...1c.br6l2DCzBrI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=32702e2e2cdf27bc&biw=1306&bih=905) (meaning "Go away!", "Be off with you!").

---

EDIT: Per comments below, I would just note this one semantic distinction...

> 1: *"I'm trying to get hold **of** John"* (to *locate, contact, communicate with* him)
>    2:  *"I'm trying to get a hold **on** John"* (to physically *grasp* him, or metaphorically *understand* him)

There's a certain amount of flexibility in the above constructions (dialectally, at least, #1 could use ***ahold***, and it *could* carry the sense of #2). But the #1 *make contact* sense always needs ***of***, and if you try replacing ***hold*** with ***grip, grab*** - with or without preceding ***get [a]*** - it should be clear that *idiomatically*, certain forms either don't work at all, or have restricted (probable) meanings.

Comment: In fact, "get/lay/grab/have/take hold of" seems to be the original form of the idiom. The word "a" was added later, and is still much less common. As you say, it doesn't make a lot of sense as an article, and many Americans currently spell it "ahold" in this idiom. This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+a+hold%2Ctake+ahold&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=20) compares "take a hold" and "take ahold"; "take a hold" shows up around 1780, while "take hold" was around for two centuries before that (Shakespeare used it), and dwarfs both lines on this Ngram.

Comment: @Peter and Fumble: I don't really follow why the article here would not make sense. It's quite parallel to _get **a** grip on_ or even the colloquial _get **a** load of this_, where I have never in my life seen anyone write _*agrip_ or _*aload_, not have I ever heard anyone use either without an article.

Comment: @Janus: I think it's all about the preposition. Compare, say, *"All team members need a firm hold **on** the rope in tug-of-war"* with *"Here - take hold **of** this rope"*. Not so good if you swap those prepositions, imho. It seems to me *to take/get hold of* is more of a "phrasal verb". On the other hand, ***grip*** doesn't work without an article in that construction, and ***grab*** simply doesn't work at all. The slight syntactic differences between ***hold, grip, grab*** (as both noun and verb usages) are quite intriguing.

Comment: ...also note @Redska's now-deleted offering *"I'm trying to **get hold of** John"*. No-one would ever include ***a*** there if they meant *trying to **contact** John*, nor would they use ***on***.

Comment: @Fumble I would never use _on_ for the sense of trying to contact someone; but I would certainly include the article. It sounds slightly stiff and formal to me without it (which is a bit odd considering it's a fairly colloquial expression). “I'm trying to get a hold of the landlord—there's a burst pipe in the kitchen” is perfectly natural to me (and many others, if Uncle Google is to be trusted).

Comment: @Janus: Personally, I'd *never* use the article in the "contact" sense, but there's obviously scope for some variation there. If *my* Uncle Google (Books) is to be trusted, there are over 18000 instancves of [*trying to get hold of him*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trying+to+get+hold+of+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), compared to 1200 with ***a hold*** and just 454 with ***ahold***. The ratios are even more pronounced with *...of him on the phone*, which eliminates any chance of false positives for the *physical grab, grip* sense.

Comment: @Janus: you're right; the article makes sense here. I was thinking of *"ahold/a hold"* as an adverb and not a noun.

Comment: @Peter, Janus: It seems to me the preposition is crucial. Nobody says *"get hold **on** yourself"*. The issue is whether *get hold **of** [something]* is a phrasal verb. [Apparently it is](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+a+hold+on+yourself%2Cget+a+hold+of+yourself%2Cget+hold+on+yourself%2Cget+hold+of+yourself&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20a%20hold%20on%20yourself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20a%20hold%20of%20yourself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20hold%20of%20yourself%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

First off, [*any* time you have '**get**' followed by some noun form of an action verb](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/77994#eid3128014), it's going to have the sense

> - to succeed in ~ing, to have an opportunity to ~

---

---

so, in this instance,

> **[Get hold of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20hold%20of)**
>
> 1. to succeed in grasping, to happen to get a hold upon.
>
>    > Matthew Kellison, *[A Survey of the New Religion](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=eLhoAAAAcAAJ)*, 1603, [p. 664](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=eLhoAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA664):
>    >
>    > > For if a man by ſhipvvracke vvere in daunger of drovving, then ſo longe as he ſeeth humaine meanes to ſaue him, he vvill ſnatch at a cord vvhich is caſt vnto him, or he vvill reach for a borde, or ſeeke to get hold of a boate, rocke, or tree, to helpe him ſelfe by; & if he be an Atheiſt, then ſo longe as theſe meanes faile not, he ſeeketh for no other, but if he perceue, that by no creaturs helpe, he can be holpen, then be he Chriſtian or Pagane, Ievv or Atheiſt, he thinketh vppon ſome higher povver, and vvhen all creaturs forſake him, and his ovvn force vvill no more ſerue him, nature bidds him to ſeeke farther, & to demaund that helpe of the Creatour, vvhich no creature can yeeld him.
> 2. (*figuratively*, *of objects*) to succeed in gaining possession of, to get.
> 3. (*figuratively*, *of concepts*) [to succeed in grasping intellectually, to gain an understanding of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-hold-of).
> 4. (*figuratively*, *of other people*) to succeed in reaching, to make contact with.

So, all in all, pretty useful and fills a need in the language for communicating both success *and* the longing and effort that preceded it.

Some dictionaries (e.g., [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20hold%20of)) consider this the most proper form and [it's certainly seen more usage than the others](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+hold+of%2Cget+ahold+of%2Cget+a+hold+of%2Cget+an+hold+of&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). All the same, as an American, I'd only instinctively use it for the first sense and process—and use—the three figurative senses as clipped forms of 'get ahold of'.

---

---

Pace @NewAlexandria & co., there's nothing substandard or confusing about

> **Get ahold of**
>
> 1. [*alt. form of*] **get hold of**, emphasizing the specific strong action involved.
>
> > *Graham's Magazine*, Aug. 1850, p. 119:
> >
> > > The good sailor who had caught ahold of her when she was fallin', told her to cheer up.

It's a straightforward application of the English prefix '[a-](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/270754)' based on the old ['a' variant](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8) of 'on'. Specifically:

> [**ahold**, *adv.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4286)
>
> 2. So as to hold on to someone or something; with a firm hold or grip. Chiefly with *of*.

Some dictionaries (e.g., [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-hold-of)) affect that this is an Americanism, but the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4286) and [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20hold%20of) note that it appears elsewhere in vernacular and regional British English as well. The truly colloquial American form is ['aholt'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/314184).

[@Nora is right](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75504/171986) that the [cretic rhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretic) of 'get ahold' is the main reason to prefer it to the [spondee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spondee) of 'get hold'. This discomfort means the speaker has to make a particular effort to say it this way and @JanusBahsJacquet correctly pointed out above that this makes 'get hold' sound more formal and stilted than it really should be. Moreover, the adverb also emphasizes the action being described and heightens its force, which makes it superior for any of the figurative senses of the phrase.

---

---

> **Get a hold of**
>
> 1. to get a [cargo hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hold_(compartment)) of.
> 2. [*Misspelling of*] **get ahold of**.
> 3. [*Mistake for*] **get a hold on**.

@NewAlexandria has this one backwards as well. It's 'get a hold of' that can be accepted as a common enough regional idiom but which makes no sense based on its component parts. It either uses *a* as a preposition meaning 'on' ([which hasn't been standard since the 1700s](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8) outside of set phrases like 'once a year' or in dialects like Geordie) or treats it as the indefinite article, which doesn't work with its following preposition 'on' unless you're describing a 'hold's-worth' of something, which only works with as a clipping for 'cargo hold'.

Obviously, I'd never use this form myself but plenty do, probably mostly because they take it as the indefinite article, don't sweat the trailing preposition's mismatch, and don't realize that *ahold* is a perfectly valid word.

Answer (score -1):

"get a hold of" is the only proper form.  I would prefer this in all circumstances since it is correct use of the language.

"Ahold" is not a proper word.

"ahold of" is a colloquialism, but the OED does not define "ahold" as a word out of context of the colloquialism.

"get hold of" is just a broken form, where the speaker couldn't manage to use the article
 *"a"*.

I suppose I would use the incorrect forms in social contexts where being seen as a ['non-native speaker'](http://www.englishforums.com/English/SpotANonNativeSpeaker/pvv/post.htm) would put me danger  (perhaps if I was confronted by gang members)

Comment: The phrase "get hold of" is older and far more common than either "get a hold of" or "get ahold of"; it seems to be the original form. I don't think you can call it a broken form. See this [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+hold+of%2Cget+a+hold+of%2Cget+ahold+of&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10).

Comment: @PeterShor "aint" has a history of usage in print - [that] doesn't make it correct. Note here I could have left off the work "that" and the sentence would still have read correctly (by ear/eye) yet would not have been correct usage of the language.   But after some review of the Ngam grapher, I do have to give credence to your position.  'Get hold' and 'take hold' have a long history of usage in the language.

Comment: I suspect that the origin of "take hold of" was that "hold" was a mass noun, as is "possession" in "take possession of". Now "hold" is no longer used as a mass noun outside of the idioms "take/get/lay/keep hold of".

Comment: [Yes, the OED does, providing cites back to the 19th century](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4286). Their 'regional' indicates regional British dialects, in addition to its American use. Further, it's a perfectly straightforward coinage from [*a-*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8).